# Can I write to a const member of a non-const struct?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards

Is this code legal?:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct a_d{
    int const x;
} a_d;

int a_d__ctor(a_d *X)
{
    *(int*)&X->x = 42; //<-- legal or not?
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    a_d a;
    a_d__ctor(&a);
    printf("a.x=%d\n", a.x);

}
```

Comment: @smac89 The Standard I guess.

Comment: @Yousaf, maybe. This is a standards kind of issue, so whatever the standards say it should be. It could also be undefined, in which case speculations shall prevail

Comment: I wonder if there is anything that makes `struct a foo(const struct a, const int c) { struct a result = { a.b, c }; return result; }` with `struct a { int b, const int c };` undefined behaviour or otherwise precluded. (In any case, this would be my preferred workaround -- although I'm definitely not a language lawyer, so it might be UB.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal That's definitely defined (but I think I'll simply erase the const in my use case).

Comment: @PSkocik: I've been tempted to make some of the members in my matrix types const -- the ones that should never change during the lifetime of the variable -- as the actual data resides in a separate reference-counted object; the matrix variable itself should be immutable for its lifetime, as it only describes the data location and arrangement. Thus far, I've resisted the temptation, and simply resorted to documenting the typical use cases in comments near the declaration. It is still an open question to me which one is better, especially for learners and new programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modyfing an object declared with `const` qualifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

According to the Standard (emphasis mine):

> #### C11 6.7.3/6 *Type qualifiers*
>
> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
>   const-qualified type **through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified
>   type**, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Can you provide a proof that `x` is indeed const qualified? The `X->x` is indeed a const-qualified l-value expression but it does not prove that `X->x` object is actually const.